# initialized string in MASM struture

Tags: string, assembly, struct, global-variables, masm

In C I have this structure

```
struct frame
{
    int whidth;
    int height;
    char* name;
};
```

I want the same in MASM

```
frame STRUCT
    name
    whidth  DWORD   ?
    height  DWORD   ?
    name
frame ENDS
```

for the name I can write ",name  DWORD  ?" and affect by an adress'string at runtime
but I want to initilized it.
I try this :

```
c1 db "big",0
c2 db "medium",0
c3 db "small",0

Frames frame <100, 50, c1>,<80, 30, c2>,<50, 20, c3>
```

It's not working !
I also try this

```
frame STRUCT
    name    DB <>   ?
    whidth  DWORD   ?
    height  DWORD   ?
    name
frame ENDS
```

don't work !

and this makes me strings of equal length filled with spaces ...

```
Frames frame <100, 50, "big">,<80, 30, "medium">,<50, 20, "small">
```

What's the right syntax?

Answer (score 2):

You chose to omit some pretty important information from your question; the actual error message(s) you were getting.

The error messages I get for the `DWORD ?` variant are:

```
error A2008: syntax error : name
error A2036: too many initial values for structure
```

So let's [look up](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/ml-nonfatal-error-a2008?view=msvc-160) error A2008:

> syntax error :
>
> A token at the current location caused a syntax error.
>
> One of the following may have occurred:
>
> - A dot prefix was added to or omitted from a directive.
> - A reserved word (such as C or SIZE) was used as an identifier.
> - An instruction was used that was not available with the current processor or coprocessor selection.
> - A comparison run-time operator (such as ==) was used in a conditional assembly statement instead of a relational operator (such as EQ).
> - An instruction or directive was given too few operands.
> - An obsolete directive was used.

A few of these talk about directives, so let's open [the list of MASM directives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/directives-reference?view=msvc-160). Sure enough, `NAME` is listed as a directive. This means that you can't use `NAME` for your own symbols, since that falls under *"A reserved word (such as C or SIZE) was used as an identifier"*. And because reserved words are case-insensitive that also rules out use of `name` for your own symbols.

So now you have two options:

1. Call the field something other than `name`.
2. If you don't need the `NAME` directive in your program you can remove its reserved word status using `option nokeyword:<name>`. You can then freely call your struct field `name`.

---

As far as initializing the field is concerned; the variant with `DWORD ?` would be the one most closely matching the C code, since only the address of the string gets stored in the struct, just like in the C code.

Answer (score 0):

I found this "obvious" solution thanks for your help.

```
frame STRUCT
    name    DWORD   ?
    whidth  DWORD   ?
    height  DWORD   ?
    name
frame ENDS

c1 db "big",0
c2 db "medium",0
c3 db "small",0

Frames DWORD c1
       DWORD 100
       DWORD 50
       DWORD c2
       DWORD 80
       DWORD 30
       DWORD c3
       DWORD 50
       DWORD 20
```

Comment: `Frames frame <100, 50, c1>,<80, 30, c2>,<50, 20, c3>` works just fine with MASM 6.14.8444 (assuming that `name    DWORD   ?` is placed last in the struct declaration). The issue is that, by default `name` is a reserved word.