# Why did I get "too many initial values for structure"

Tags: assembly, masm, masm32

I tried to create structure (you may see it in code below), but when I craete the structure item I get error "error A2036: too many initial values for structure". What wrong with it?

```
.686
.model flat, stdcall
option casemap:none

include C:\masm32\include\windows.inc
include C:\masm32\include\user32.inc
include C:\masm32\include\kernel32.inc
include C:\masm32\include\masm32.inc
includelib C:\masm32\lib\user32.lib
includelib C:\masm32\lib\kernel32.lib
includeLib C:\masm32\lib\masm32.lib

Good STRUCT
    Title       BYTE 20 DUP(?)
    Description BYTE 20 DUP(?)
    Price       DWORD ?
    Count       DWORD ?
Good ENDS

.data    

    good_1 Good <"Macbook", "Notebook", 1600, 13>
    good_2 Good <"Ipad", "Ipad", 800, 24>
    good_3 Good <"Test", "Test", 250, 24>
```

In each row I get the same error, but I entered correct number of initial values.

Comment: Judging by this QA: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66630587/initialized-string-in-masm-struture - I'm guessing the problem is actually that you're using a reserved-name for one of your struct members (probably "Title", "Description" or "Count").

Comment: Thanks Dai, the problem was in "Title", that's reserved-name.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Dai comment, I found that the problem is in "Title" reserved-name.